# Error While Starting Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I have upgraded from Android Studio 1.5 to 2.0 yesterday (Using Linux Mint 17.3) . It worked well. But from today morning whenever I start my Android Studio it shows a dialogue box with error:

```
Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: error: cannot open '/tmp/adb.log': Permission denied
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
'/home/shahid/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

I have tried adb kill-server, adb start-server. Almost same error in the terminal.

Comment: can you run it with "sudo"?

Comment: Thanks fro your reply. I tried **adb root** command, nothing happened. Finally I uninstalled everything and reinstalled the whole Android Studio again. Now it's working fine. The reason for the problem might be running both Android studio and Genymotion at the same time.